# How can I make git rev-list --bisect skip specific commits?

Tags: git

I'm writing a script that performs a binary search to assign blame for broken tests.  I'm using `git rev-list --bisect`.

I'd like to exclude specific commits where the build is broken.  `git bisect` has an option to do this, with `git bisect skip BROKENCOMMIT`.  However, I can't find an equivalent way to do the same thing using `git rev-list --bisect`.  Is there one?

Thanks!

Comment: git rev-list has options to exclude commits based on author, committer, date and description.  Why oh why doesn't it have an option to exclude commits based on the hash?

Comment: I ended up just running git rev-list, getting the entire list of commits, then doing everything else manually.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not a way to tell `git rev-list --bisect` to skip certain commits.

`git bisect` implements skipping by creating references named `refs/bisect/skip-*`.  Good and bad commits are stored in `refs/bisect/bad` and `refs/bisect/good-*`.  The `git rev-list --bisect` command looks at `refs/bisect/bad` and `refs/bisect/good-*`, but does not pay attention to `refs/bisect/skip-*` for some mysterious reason.  It seems like that would be a good suggestion for the Git mailing list.

Instead of `rev-list --bisect`, you could use `git bisect start --no-checkout`, use `git bisect skip` to add the commits you want to skip, and then use the `BISECT_HEAD` reference.  One disadvantage of this approach is `git bisect` doesn't allow you to specify the ref name space, so if there's an existing bisect in progress you'll overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

As a side-effect of [`git rev-list --bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#_bisection_helpers) *not* skipping *any* commit, `gitCommitByP4Change` (from [`git p4`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4) in [`git-p4.py`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6d5b26420848ec3bc7eae46a7ffa54f20276249d/git-p4.py#L3308)) can enter an infinite loop.

See [commit d15068a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d15068a6501bec72fddec9f79372a5e3ce5e1379), [commit 607a3be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/607a3be6d0f3144b311bfe2fd2b0e5ab4a250e89), [commit a2bee10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2bee10ad9ed4dc45c1f7da76f01388925b80212), [commit d604520](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6045201fcec7bd9738fea4daf9d176d8df9f5ba), [commit ff8c50e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff8c50ed0c98d9bc6aaf5fc2e93bd976c3076750), [commit f2768cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2768cb343cb0320f79692625dea7f50af643759), [commit b30efb1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b30efb156f148081bfb912a2269666864e3937b2), [commit 2dda741](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2dda741279ba3c56340f3bd88745604bb5a394a6) (01 Apr 2019) by [Mazo, Andrey (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 44275f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/44275f5e1bef37304f5a9da65b588e344eb00a72), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `git-p4`: detect/prevent infinite loop in `gitCommitByP4Change()`
>
> Under certain circumstances, `gitCommitByP4Change()` can enter an infinite loop resulting in `git p4 sync` hanging forever.
>
> The problem is that `git rev-list --bisect <latest> ^<earliest>` can return `<latest>`, which would result in reinspecting `<latest>` and potentially an infinite loop.
>
> This can happen when importing just a subset of P4 repository and/or with explicit "`--changesfile`" option.
>
> A real-life example:
>
> ```
> looking in ref refs/remotes/p4/mybranch for change 26894 using bisect...
> Reading pipe: git rev-parse refs/remotes/p4/mybranch
> trying: earliest  latest 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> Reading pipe: git rev-list --bisect 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> Reading pipe: git cat-file commit 147f5d3292af2e1cc4a56a7b96db845144c68486
> current change 25339
> trying: earliest ^147f5d3292af2e1cc4a56a7b96db845144c68486 latest 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> Reading pipe: git rev-list --bisect 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1 ^147f5d3292af2e1cc4a56a7b96db845144c68486
> Reading pipe: git cat-file commit 51db83df9d588010d0bd995641c85aa0408a5bb9
> current change 25420
> trying: earliest ^51db83df9d588010d0bd995641c85aa0408a5bb9 latest 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> Reading pipe: git rev-list --bisect 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1 ^51db83df9d588010d0bd995641c85aa0408a5bb9
> Reading pipe: git cat-file commit e8f83909ceb570f5a7e48c2853f3c5d8207cea52
> current change 25448
> trying: earliest ^e8f83909ceb570f5a7e48c2853f3c5d8207cea52 latest 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> Reading pipe: git rev-list --bisect 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1 ^e8f83909ceb570f5a7e48c2853f3c5d8207cea52
> Reading pipe: git cat-file commit 09a48eb7acd594dce52e06681be9c366e1844d66
> current change 25521
> trying: earliest ^09a48eb7acd594dce52e06681be9c366e1844d66 latest 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> Reading pipe: git rev-list --bisect 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1 ^09a48eb7acd594dce52e06681be9c366e1844d66
> Reading pipe: git cat-file commit 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> current change 26907
> trying: earliest ^09a48eb7acd594dce52e06681be9c366e1844d66 latest 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> Reading pipe: git rev-list --bisect 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1 ^09a48eb7acd594dce52e06681be9c366e1844d66
> Reading pipe: git cat-file commit 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> current change 26907
> trying: earliest ^09a48eb7acd594dce52e06681be9c366e1844d66 latest 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> Reading pipe: git rev-list --bisect 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1 ^09a48eb7acd594dce52e06681be9c366e1844d66
> Reading pipe: git cat-file commit 4daff81c520a82678e1ef347f2b5e97258101ae1
> current change 26907
> ...
> ```
>
> The fix is two-fold:
>
> - detect an infinite loop and die right away instead of looping forever;
> - make sure `git rev-list --bisect` can't return "`latestCommit`" again by excluding it from the `rev-list` range explicitly.